# How to add different color to each module through a for loop? Like commented below?

Tags: python-3.x

how to add color for each module? i tried use

```
self.color ={"red","green","yellow","blue","agua","orange"}
```

in the fill, but this not work

```
    for i in self.__pop_percentage.values():
        self.extent = (i/self.__sum_pop_percentage*360)
        self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=self.start,extent=(self.extent),fill="red")
        print(i)
        self.start = self.start + self.extent
        self.count = self.count +1
    self.canvas.pack()

    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=0,extent=130.212,fill="red")
    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=130.212,extent=121.068,fill="green")
    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=251.28,extent=19.332,fill="yellow")
    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=270.612,extent=17.996,fill="blue")
    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=288.608,extent=14.9,fill="aqua")
    #self.canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=303.508,extent=56.492,fill="orange")

    #self.canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list of colors and pick the next color from that list:

```
colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "aqua", "orange"]
for color_index, i in enumerate(self.__pop_percentage.values()):
    ...
    self.canvas.create_arc(..., fill=colors[color_index])
```

Note that this will fail if you have more values than the number of colors. You may cycle colors if that is the case:

```
    self.canvas.create_arc(..., fill=colors[color_index % len(colors)])
```